# Accelerating OpenVPN using multiple connections

Tags: vpn, openvpn, bandwidth

My ISP throttles single connection downloads, but if I use an accelerator like aria2c and open lets say, 20 connections, my download speed shoots through the roof. I have been able to saturate my gigabit pipe this way.

However when I use OpenVPN, I'm not sure of how to implement this feature. Downloading files over the VPN via the accelerator still gives me very high throughput.

If anyone is able to give any pointers I'd be grateful.

Comment: If you don't have the problem when using the VPN, then why this question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The problem arises when I don't have the option to use an accelerator, for example when browsing, watching youtube or using just about any other program that doesn't support acceleration.

Comment: Are you quite sure your traffic is actually going over the VPN?

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure that the traffic is going over the VPN. I have tested this by inspecting routes.